# How can I find any domain name that resolves to IP within a given net range?

Tags: domain-name-system, subnet

For example, given the range:

```
172.128.0.0 - 172.191.255.255
```

I need to find some domain that resolves to an IP-adress within the range. Is it possible ? I'm using a Linux system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do reverse lookups on each IP in the range and search through the results for the domain you're looking for. However, this will only work if the person/s responsible for that domain created a PTR record for the IP.

This is a quick and dirty working example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
ipAddrRange function ripped from:
http://vinojdavis.blogspot.com/2009/02/def-ipaddrrangestartaddr-endaddr-def.html
"""

import sys
import socket

def ipAddrRange(startAddr, endAddr):
    def incrAddr(addrList):
        addrList[3] += 1
        for i in (3,2,1):
            if addrList[i] == 256:
                addrList[i] = 0
                addrList[i-1] += 1
    def asString(addrList):
        return ".".join(map(str,addrList))
    startAddrList = map(int,startAddr.split("."))
    endAddrList = map(int,endAddr.split("."))
    curAddrList = startAddrList[:]
    yield asString(curAddrList)
    for i in range(4):
        while curAddrList[i] < endAddrList[i]:
            incrAddr(curAddrList)
            yield asString(curAddrList)

if len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1]:
    domain_filter = sys.argv[1]
else:
    domain_filter = ""

for addr in ipAddrRange("172.128.0.0","172.191.255.255"):
    ptr = socket.gethostbyaddr(addr)[0]
    if domain_filter:
        if domain_filter in ptr:
            print ptr
    else:
        print ptr
```

Example run:

```
# ./reverse_spy.py aol
AC800000.ipt.aol.com
AC800001.ipt.aol.com
```

You can limit output to results matching the optional argument.

Also, limit your range as your example range is 4194304 IPs long. ;) Have people looking for ya with ranges like that.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to find *any* DNS name that resolves to a specific IP; or are you trying to find *all* DNS names that resolve to an IP. The latter is impossible. The former is easily accomplished on almost any OS with:

```
nslookup
set type=ptr
(reversed-ip).in-addr.arpa
```

The (reversed-ip) part is what it sounds like. If your IP is 1.2.3.4, then reversed would be 4.3.2.1, and the third line would be:

```
4.3.2.1.in-addr.arpa
```

Comment: That will only work if reverse DNS has been set up and is one of the reasons some people don't set it up.

Answer (score 1):

According to ARIN, 172.128.0.0/10 is owned by AOL.  You could try querying AOL's listed DNS servers to see if they have reverse entries for the IP you're interested in.  (Go to arin.net and search their whois for that network address.)

Answer (score 1):

`nmap -sL -R 172.128-191.0-255.0-255`

`-sL` lists the hosts without scanning. `-R` forces DNS resolution.